Will a subfloor barricade over concrete result in a warmer floor?
I'm looking at laying loose planks (likely going to glue them down) in my basement rental. We don't have moisture problems and the foundation is good. We also are at a higher elevation and nowhere near a floodplain.
What I've gotten on mixed advice from four flooring places is whether I should spend the money on a subfloor. Likely using the barricade product from Rona. Since moisture isn't a problem, what I'm wondering is will it make a difference in the floor temperature. Two flooring places said it will be colder, but just add a baseboard heater and it would be fine. Another said the barricade subfloor would make a massive difference. What we currently have is some thin 4mm click sitting on that dmx puckered plastic sheeting in case of moisture, it just was too flexible and probably is the reason our floor has cracked the way it has.
The basement overall is fairly flat. Definitely some slight sinks that I believe some shims would help with. Or maybe securing the subfloor to the concrete might make those less noticeable in the sense the bounce will be gone (or at least reduced). But, a lot of products don't want you to glue loose lay to plywood resin materials like barricade, only to plywood tops.
Do people have better experiences laying loose lay glued to concrete? I live in southern Canada, it does have cold winters. Or would it be worth spending the extra money, dropping a barricade (Rona brand) subfloor panels and gluing down to that (which two flooring installers said that's what they would do)? I don't really have the height to lay a subfloor, secure plywood tops, then glue down which some subfloor plywood composite manufacturers recommend.

Most hard type flooring only allows for a certain height difference(3/16?) from flat.  If possible, a warmer floor usually makes people more happy.

If the floor is as uneven as you say, gluing something down will only highlight the condition. This being a rental, putting a subfloor in will side step complaints about cold floors, as well.
Use a floor leveler to take out the high spots. Lay your barricade on top of the smoothed floor. The instructions will tell you to leave a 1/4" gap around the perimeter. Fill the gap with a joint backer rod as a cushion and air barrier. Install a floating floor on top of the barricade.
